# Unable to dispatch function call in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to redux,While performing below example i cant render the output as expected.

App.js

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import store from './store';
    import CakeContainer from './CakeContainer'
    
    function App(props) {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
         <CakeContainer />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

store.js

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';

const initialState = {cake:10}
const cakeReducer = (state = initialState,action) =>{
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'BUY_CAKE':
        return {
            ...state,
            cake : 5,
        }
        default :return state
    }
}
const store=createStore(cakeReducer);

export default store;
```

CakeContainer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function CakeContainer(props) {
    return <div>
            {props.buycake}
            <h1>Store cakes:{props.cake}</h1>
            </div> ;
}
const mapStateToProps= state =>{
    return {
        cake: state.cake
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch =>{
    return {
        buycake: () => dispatch({type:'BUY_CAKE'} )
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) (CakeContainer);
```

Console display warning as below : Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Can anyone please help me why buycake() is not rendered here and the output is cake:10 always in stead of cake:5.

Comment: use case "BUY_CAKE": not this case 'BUY_CAKE':

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{props.buycake}
```

This line is trying to render a function onto the screen. That's not possible, and is causing the error you see. Presumably, you want to call the function, but i'm not sure when. Supposing you want to do it when a button is clicked, it might look like this:

```
function CakeContainer(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.buycake}>Click Me</button>
      <h1>Store cakes:{props.cake}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks ...It worked i thought it would call {props.buyCake} during page loads.